# How make this even count code faster?

Tags: c++, count, numbers

The following code is meant to find total numbers between `l` and `r` whose product of digits is even (for multiple test cases `t`). This code runs perfectly but is extremely slow for `r` greater than 100000. Can anyone suggest a better alternative?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
long long int nd(long long int x, int n) //return the digit at a particular index    staring with zero as index for unit place
{
while (n--) {
    x /= 10;
}
return (x % 10);
}
int ng(long long int number) //returns total number of digits in an integer
{
int digits = 0;
if (number < 0) digits = 1;
while (number) {
    number /= 10;
    digits++;
}
return digits;
}

int main()
{
int t;
cin>>t;
long long int l[t], r[t], c;
for(long long int j=0;j<t;j++)
{
    cin>>l[j]>>r[j];
}
for(long long int k=0;k<t;k++)
{    
  long long int sum=0;
  long long int t=0;

  for(long long int i=l[k];i<=r[k];i++)
  {
   while(t<ng(i))
   {
       c=nd(i,t);
       if((c%2)==0)
       {
           ++sum;
           break;
       }
       ++t;
    }
   t=0;    
  }
 cout<<sum<<endl;
}    
cin.ignore();
cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be nice if you could document your current approach so we could tell if your implementation was faulty as opposed to the approach.

Comment: And slightly more meaningful method names would help!

Comment: This would have been a good candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Could you add some example inputs, everything I've tried is quick (even with r=1000000)

Comment: I don't know how you can measure the speed; the code you posted doesn't even compile.

Comment: try it with t = 2
and l and r 1 10000000 and 1 1000000000

Comment: @JamesKanze - thats not true it compiles perfectly

Comment: It's not legal C++, and if it compiles, you're using g++, and you've invoked it incorrectly.  Try `g++ -std=c++03...`.

Comment: @jamesKanze - what you are saying is true.The error might be possibly due to the variable sized array which are not allowed in standard c++ compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All numbers starting with, e.g., 10…, 12…, 14…, …, 2…, 30…,  already are known to have an even product of digits. I would therefore start from the left (more significant digits) and count in blocks. There are only a few numbers whose product of digits is odd (such as 1111111111), only here you have to dig deeper.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
int count(String prefix, int digits) {
  int result = 0;
  if (digits == 0)
    return 0;
  for (int d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
    if (d%2 == 0)
      result += 10**(digits-1);
    else
      result += count(prefix . toString(d), digits-1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

This would be called like `count("2", 8)` to get the count for the interval from 200000000 to 299999999.

---

Here is a Haskell implementation for a whole block (i.e., all *d*-digit numbers):

```
blockcount :: Integer -> Integer
blockcount 0 = 0
blockcount d = 5 * 10^(d-1) + 5 * blockcount (d-1)
```

E.g., `blockcount 1000` is calculated to be 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999066736381496781121009910455276182830382908553628291975378285660204033089024224365545559672902118897640405010069675757375784512478645967605158479182796069243765589333861674849726004924014098168488899509203734886881759487485204066209194821728874584896189301621145573518880530185771339040777982337089557201543830551112852533471993671631547352570738170137834797206804710506392882149336331258934560194469281863679400155173958045898786770370130497805485390095785391331638755207047965173135382342073083952579934063610958262104177881634921954443371555726074612482872145203218443653596285122318233100144607930734560575991288026325298250137373309252703237464196070623766166018953072125441394746303558349609375 in much less than a second.

You’d still have to add code that breaks your range into suitable blocks.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to loop through each digit of a number and see if it's even. If it is, the whole product will be even and there's no need to check the remaining digits.

The problem with your code is that you run trough the number multiple times looking for a digit with index `i`. You should simply run through the number's digits once checking for evenness along the way.

Here's a self-explanatory Go code implementing the algorithm:

```
package main

func iseven(num int) bool {
    for num > 0 {
        digit := num % 10
        if digit&1 == 0 {  # same as digit%2 == 0, only simpler
            return true
        }
        num /= 10
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    sum := 0
    for n := 1; n < 1000000; n++ {
        if iseven(n) {
            sum++
        }
    }
    println(sum)
}
```

Performance on my machine:

```
λ time go run main.go
980469
go run main.go  0.05s user 0.01s system 81% cpu 0.073 total
```

**Update**

If you need to work with ginormous numbers, then a more efficient approach can be used.

Let's call the numbers that have the product of their digits odd *dodd numbers*. So, `135` is a dodd number, `134` is not. Similarly, numbers that have the product of their digits even are called *deven*. So `134` is a deven number.

As has been mentioned earlier, only numbers that consist of odd digits are dodd. So instead of enumerating numbers, we can just count the numbers comprised of digits `1`, `3`, `5`, `7`, and `9`. For integer `N > 1`, there are exactly `10^N - 10^(N-1)` numbers that have `N` digits. And of those numbers, `5 ^ N` are dodd, and therefore `10^N - 10^(N-1) - 5^N` are deven.

The approach is to count how many dodd numbers there are in between the `left` and `right` bounds and then subtract that count from the total count of numbers between `left` and `right`. You could also count just deven numbers, but that is a bit trickier.

Effectively, you're going to loop through digits with this approach, instead of through numbers. My [implementation](https://github.com/alco/count_deven/blob/master/count.py) in Python is able to compute the number of deven numbers between `1` and `int("1" * 100000)` (a number with **10000** digits) in under one second.

Comment: Why is `digit&1` simpler than `digit % 2`?  The second expresses what is wanted; the first obfuscates.

Comment: @JamesKanze `&1` doesn't obfuscate it any more than `%2` does. If you're aiming at zero obfuscation, you would write a function `is_even` and use it instead.

Comment: The definition of an even number is one which is divisible by 2.  In other words, one which has a remainder of 0 when divided by 2.  In other words, one for which `number % 2 == 0`.  There is some argument for putting it into a named function, but using bitwise operators for it is obfuscation.

Comment: @JamesKanze - It's only obfuscation if you expect future readers of the code to be completely ignorant of the nature of the binary representation of numbers and completely ignorant of bitwise logic.  If they are ignorant of either of these, using `&1` would be helpful, in an educational sense, for such an individual.  As to which method is "simpler", that's purely a matter of opinion.  Once compiled, either method should result in `&1` using a decent compiler.

Comment: It's obfuscation to say one thing and mean another.  The code should express the _why_: do I want to know if the bit 0 (in a bitmask type) is set, or do I want to know if the value is divisible by two.  It has nothing to do with knowing the internal representation on a machine or not; it has to do with expressing your higher level intent.

Comment: @android - try it n<1000000000 it should run within 1 second to be successful...Otherwise a still better approach is needed

Answer (score 0):

An optimisation based on the following would work:

Multiplying two numbers together gets you oddness / evenness according to the rule

```
even * even = even
odd * even = even * odd = even
odd * odd = odd
```

Therefore you only need to track the last digit of your number numbers.

I'm too old to code this but I bet it would be blisteringly quick as you only need to consider numbers between 0 and 9.

Comment: The question says that they are looking for numbers _whose product of digits is even_; e.g., 481 is odd, but the 4*8*1 is even.

Comment: Oops. Feel free to downvote me chirlu; I'll take it like a cat!

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what your code is doing, but the basic
principles are simple:

- `value % 10` is the low order digit
- `value /= 10` removes the low order digit
- if any digit is even, then the product will be even.

This should lead to a very simple loop for each value.  (You may
have to special case `0`.)

Further optimizations are possible: all even numbers will have
a product of digits which is even, so you can iterate with
a step of 2, and then add in the number of evens (one half of
the range) afterwards.  This should double the speed.

One further optimization: if the low order digit is even, the number itself is even, so you don't have to extract the low order digit to test it.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to check is if one of digits in the number is even. If it is, it will have 2 as a factor, and hence be even.

You also don't seem to remember where you are up to in digits - every time you increment `t` in your `for` loop, and then call `nd(i,t)`, you count down from that `t` to zero in `nd`. This is quadratic in number of digits in the worst case. Better would be to simply break up the number into its component digits at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is change

```
  while(t<ng(i))
```

to

```
int d = ng(i);
while (t < d)
```

So ng is only called once per loop.

Also ng is just log(number)+1 (log base 10 that is)

I don't know is that will be quicker though.

Answer (score 0):

First, please fix your indentation

Your code uses too many division and loops which cause a lot of delays

```
long long int nd(long long int x, int n) //return the digit at a particular index    staring with zero as index for unit place
{
    while (n--) {
        x /= 10;
    }
    return (x % 10);
}
```

This can be fixed easily by a table lookup

```
long long int nd(long long int x, int n) //return the digit at a particular index    staring with zero as index for unit place
{
    long long int pow10[] = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000,
                             100000000, 1000000000, 10000000000, 100000000000,
                             1000000000000, 10000000000000, 100000000000000,
                             1000000000000000, 10000000000000000,
                             100000000000000000, 1000000000000000000};

    return ((x / pow10[n]) % 10);
}
```

Likewise, the ng function to get total number of digits in an integer can be changed to a fast [log10](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog10), no need to repeatedly divides and count. Ofcourse it'll need a small change to adapt 64 bit numbers

```
int ng(long long int number) //returns total number of digits in an integer
{
    int digits = 0;
    if (number < 0) digits = 1;
    while (number) {
        number /= 10;
        digits++;
    }
    return digits;
}
```